# py df groupby and get values to a string

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to group df on column 'ProductID' and populate resulted values from 'Feature' to 'Combo' as a string avoiding duplicates in it

[Input dataframe looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HmrT.jpg)

[Resulting dataframe should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t24ZF.jpg)

I can't figure out next steps after applying groupby

> `df['Combo']=pd.Series(df.groupby('ProductID')['Feature'])`

Comment: Please fix your question to include 1) your data as _text_, 2) your output as _text_, and 3) any relevant code and tracebacks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ProductID":["GD457","GD457","FE031","NA001","FE031"],
                   "Features":["Black", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red"]})
df["Combo"] = df.groupby("ProductID")["Features"].transform(lambda x: "-".join(x.unique()))
```

Comment: It does the job! Thanks a lot!